# How to ask for compressed results in a web service request (Windows Phone application)

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-7, gzip, windows-phone-7.1

I have a windows phone app that is consuming some web services through proxies generated with the SLsvcUtil tool.

Is there any way to make a compressed request (with gzip or any other compression method) to the web services, and ask for a compressed result (something like setting the Accept-Encoding header in the http request).

Answer (score 1):

See this post by MVP and WP7 programmer 'sharpgis'. http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2011/08/28/GZIP-Compressed-Web-Requests-in-WP7-Take-2.aspx

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks that's interesting, but the classes i use to make the requests are generated by a sdk tool (SLsvcUtil.exe) from a wsdl, and i cant find a way to access the underlying http request object. The generated code uses [System.ServiceModel.ClientBase.ChannelBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190431(v=vs.95).aspx) to make the request.

Comment: I came across this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/wcf/thread/8b414a3f-f06a-41a3-91e1-f3ff719cb4bc and this one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138373(v=vs.90).aspx hope that helps.